# Can I pass a cookie value from mobile website to app and vice versa

Tags: android, ios, cookies, firebase, mobile

Scenario one is I have a user who visits my mobile website and a cookie with the traffic source is created. Can I pass this cookie value via deep link so I can obtain the original traffic source?

Scenario two the user opens the app then navigates to the mobile website via deep link on the app. Could I pass a value say the referrer from the app to the mobile site?

This is for both Android and IOS.

I believe on Android I can just attached a URL parameter on the link for the referrer. But on IOS I believe I need to use a third party tool like Branch.io.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible.

If the user already has your app installed, you can simply open your app's custom url scheme from your mobile site, passing an encoded cookie, or an identifier for the user, which can then be used by the app.

However if you need to support the case where the app is not already installed, it becomes a bit more complicated. For this you would want to use a solution like [Branch.io](http://branch.io).

Using branch you can create a smart link that includes the user identifier (or encoded cookie data) and have the user select that link. Branch's system will then intelligently determine if the app is installed and take the user either to your app, or to the app store. If the user goes on to install the app, the Branch SDK will attempt to match a device fingerprint to one that was generated on a link click, and tie up the user, passing the data you used creating the link to a delegate callback (or in newer versions, a completion handler) in your app.